# How can I apply different global filters to API controllers and MVC controllers in AspNetCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I often have both MVC controllers which render HTML pages in the browser and API controllers that return JSON in the same project. API endpoints all have URLs that start with 'api/'. Obviously these two types of controllers need different treatment in systematic ways, how can I apply different global filters to each? In .net framework AspNet there was a concept of  `app.Map(new PathString("/api"), site => ConfigureApi(site));` in the Startup.Configuration, but I'm not seeing a way to translate that to AspNetCore.

Comment: You probably want to add an `[ApiController]` attribute to change binding / error handling / authentication defaults. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: About "API endpoints all have URLs that start with 'api/'  , If you use `[Route("[controller]")]` the URL won't start with  'api/'. Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.